# Error al subir imagen LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, imagen

Hola buenas consultaba ya que tengo un problema al subir una imagen, he seguido varios tutos y a ninguno les pasa el problema que me pasa

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

```
if($request->hasFile('fotoPrincipal')){
                $file =  $request->file['fotoPrincipal']; 
                $nombreArchivo = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName(); //===>Esta línea se muere. 
                $file->move(public_path() . '/img/proyectos/', $nombreArchivo);
                return $nombreArchivo;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo que no agarro laravel pero estoy viendo en otros post que para recuperar la el nombre del archivo se usa una línea así:

`$photo = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();`

tu en lugar de usar paréntesis, usas corchetes

`$file =  $request->file['fotoPrincipal'];`

y hay que validar que en el campo file de tu Form el nombre del *file* corresponda con el que estas intentando leer, en tu formulario deberías de tener algo así

`{!! Form::file('fotoPrincipal') !!}`